# Excel: Duplicates in 1 row, unique in another. Mark in another row whenever a given unique value exists across the duplicate

Tags: excel

Sorry for the verbose title, but the thing itself is rather confusing. Assuming I have

```
  A|B
555|BBB
555|RQS
888|RQS
777|BBB
777|RQS
999|LCB
999|RQS
```

I then want in column C to mark a 1 whenever A matches and B contains a specific value. In this case, BBB. So column C should be

```
1
1
0
1
1
0
0
```

I tried =SUMPRODUCT($A:$A=$B2,$B:$B="BBB"), which worked in Google Sheets, but moving it to Excel gave nothing.

Comment: @Scott Craner thanks for the code edit. I had no idea how to get the formatting correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=--(COUNTIFS(B:B,"BBB",A:A,A1)>0)
```

[image]

---

The error in your formula is that the `$B2` should be `$A2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A:$A=$A2,$B:$B="BBB")
```

But COUNTIFS() is slightly better for large datasets.

Comment: What is that "--" at the beginning doing?

Comment: it is multiplying the Boolean value by `-1*-1` turning the Boolean into the corresponding number.